# Utilizing print when expression with ireports and OpenERP7

Tags: report, field, conditional-statements

I want a textfield to be visible only when a condition is met, so I clicked on "print when expression" button and pull a field called "$F{state}". That state gets a string. What I want to do is catch when state = sent to make the textfield appear. I tried doing the following:

```
$F{Estado-state}.StringValue().equals("sent")
```

but it does not work, I need help finishing this expression.

The error I get when trying to generate a report is as follows:

Report Error

Failed to invoke method execute in class com.nantic.jasperreports.JasperServer: Error evaluating expression : 
Source text : $F{Estado-state}.StringValue().equals("draft")

Comment: Do you get an error message?  What are the results of your code?

Comment: I did not get an error in the print when expression wizard but I do get an error when I try printing the report in OpenERP, I will edit my question with the error.

Answer (score 0):

After some tries I got it working

$F{Estado-state}.equals("sent") ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE

Now it does exactly what I needed.